# Summation with Binomial Coefficients, $\sum (-1)^k \binom{m_1}{k} \binom{m_2}{k} $

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I have trouble doing this summation:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\min(m_1,m_2)} (-1)^k \binom{m_1}{k} \binom{m_2}{k} $$

where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are positive integers.

Can someone help?

Comment: I remark that the expression equals the coefficient of $x^{m_2}$ in the polynomial $(x+1)^{m_1}(x-1)^{m_2}$, if that helps at all.

Comment: @GregMartin Thank you.

Comment: related: [$\sum(-1)^k\binom mk^2$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/664769/)

Comment: @GrigoryM  Thank you. I kind of understood how to do it.

Comment: cf. http://math.stackexchange.com/q/858250/